# Shared preferences is not applied right away

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have a list of activities on clicking one of which i will get a ListView.

On this ListView here, I can apply the preferences using a menu button.  But this preferences is not applied right away to the ListView.

I have to go back and navigate my way through the parent list of activities and when i click     then only I get the preferences that I want is applied. 
cant we get this preferences/settings applied right away after we apply it?

Answer (score 2):

But the view I am applying is through a cursoradapter. When I put this cursor inside OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener it gives me some constructor error "The constructor MyCountriesActivity.MySimpleCursorAdapter(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(){}, int, Cursor, String[], int[]) is undefined". I tried to adjust the constructor in MySimpleCursorAdapter  accordingly but I am not being able to do that. What is the solution?

```
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() { 
          public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) { 
            // Implementation
              int sort = prefs.getInt("sort_pref", -1); // -1 will be the result if no preference was set before 
                if(sort == 1) 
                    sortOrder = "year";//sort on year 
                else if (sort == 2)
                    sortOrder = "country";//sort on country


                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

                Cursor c = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, sortOrder);     
                String[] from = new String[] { "year", "country" };
                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.year, R.id.country };       
                SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.country_row,
                        c, from, to);  
                setListAdapter(sca);
          } 
        }; 

        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener); 
}


class MySimpleCursorAdapter  extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override   // Called when updating the ListView
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        /* Reuse super handling ==> A TextView from R.layout.list_item */
        View v =  super.getView(position,convertView,parent); 

        TextView tYear = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.year);
        TextView tCountry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.country);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()); 
        boolean font_size = prefs.getBoolean("fontSize", false);
        boolean italic_font = prefs.getBoolean("fontItalic", false);


        String listpref = prefs.getString("bgColor", "#ffffff80");
        //System.out.println(listpref);
        tYear.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(listpref));
        tCountry.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(listpref));


        if (font_size){
            tYear.setTextSize(25);
            tCountry.setTextSize(25);
        }


        if (italic_font){
            tYear.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
            tCountry.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
        }

        return v;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, read the error message. In this line: `SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.country_row, c, from, to);` you make a new MySimpleCursorAdapter with `this` as the first arg. "This" is the listener in that case, and your constructor does not require an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

Comment: I didnt get your point. I already have MySimpleCursorAdapter in place  with a constructor  which I am using for other purpose apart from this OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. Now when i try to use the same mysimplecursoradapter i cant fix the constructor error problem

Comment: Look at the constructor for MySimpleCursorAdapter. The first arg is for a `Context`. In the line I pointed out, you have `this` as the first arg. However, `this` is not a `Context` object. Try replacing it with one of the `get*Context()` methods.

Comment: yes when i used the first arg as getContext() it worked thanks for that. but still i have one issue. the preferences is working well with checkboxes but not with listpreferences. when i choose one of the list preferences it doesnt work and then the checkboxes thereafter also dont work. when i go back to the mainlist and work through this listpreferences also show effect but not right away. for listprefernces[String listpref = prefs.getString("bgColor", "#ffffff80");] also for my arrays [<string-array name="list">] and[<string-array name="listValues">] and  <ListPreference android:key="bgColor"

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without any real code. You may want to mark this question answered, as it was in regards to setting prefs automatically. As for your new problem, you may want to store colors as `int`, like `0xff000000` rather than `String`

Comment: actually its not just with listpreferences, this listener works for couple of times and then it doesnt work..even when i change the preferences..i dont know whats this issue now

Answer (score 0):

You can add `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to your Activity:

`public class MyList extends ListActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {`

and define the `onSharedPreferenceChange()` method to manually alter settings immediately. You'll have to use `SharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)` as well.

Comment: But the view I am applying is through a custom cursoradapter that  extends cursoradapter in onCreate. I have some idea that I have to write OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in my Oncreate, but how can I do that. My cursor adapter is in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

```
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() { 
       public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                String key) {
           SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
           int sort = prefs.getInt("sort_pref", -1); // -1 will be the result if no preference was set before 
           if(sort == 1) 
               sortOrder = "year";//sort on year 
           else if (sort == 2)
               sortOrder = "country";//sort on country

            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

            Cursor c = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, sortOrder);     
            String[] from = new String[] { "year", "country" };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.year, R.id.country };       
            SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.country_row,
                    c, from, to);  
            setListAdapter(sca);
            //System.out.println("sjfs");



        }
    };

    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```